# Deleting cell elements who's arrays have a string length less than n (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, while-loop, cell

I have a cell full of strings. I want to reconstruct this cell, C, to contain only values of strings whose string length is n and higher. I have the following code, but it's not working out:

```
j=1;
 while(j<length(C))
j=j+1;
y = length(cellstr(C(j)));
  if(y<req)
    C(j) = [];
  end
 end
```

Where req is the lower bound for my new desired cell. That is, I had a cell with many strings. I wanted a new cell whose elements are only length req or higher.

However, I'm still getting values in my new constructed cell that are shorter than my threshold. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: From : y<req To : y>req

Comment: @jdweng why? If threshold is say 10, wouldn't that delete the values of y that are 10 or higher?

Comment: Actually you're skipping elements. When you delete element j, element j+1 becomes element j. You go from looking at element j to element j+2

Comment: You are collecting items less than req instead of greater equal.

Answer (score 2):

You never evaluate the first item, since `j` is set to `2` at the first iteration. You need also to access C with brackets: `C{j}`.

Here the code:

```
C = {'aa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccccc', 'ddddddddd', 'eee'};

req = 5;
j=0;
while(j<length(C))
    j=j+1;
    y = length(C{j});
    if(y<req)
        C(j) = [];
    end
end
```

Or you can use `cellfun` like:

```
req = 5;
C = C(cellfun(@length,C)>=req);
```

In both cases the output will be:

```
C = 
    'bbbbb'    'ccccccc'    'ddddddddd'
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
C(cellfun(@length,C)< req) = [];
```

See the documentation for [`cellfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `j=j+1` is at the beginning, so it misses the first element, you change the length of `C` while you loop over it, so you skip some elements and `cellstr` is for turning a character array into a cell array not getting a string from a cell array. You could do:

```
req = 3;
C = {'a' 'ab' 'abc' 'abcd' 'abcde' 'b'};
j=1;
while(j<=length(C))
y = length(C{j});
  if(y<req)
    C(j) = [];
  else
    j = j+1;
  end
end
```

or simply:

```
req = 3;
C = {'a' 'ab' 'abc' 'abcd' 'abcde' 'b'};
C = C(cellfun(@length,C) >= req)
```